# TFS Code Coverage on startup screen?

Tags: tfs, code-coverage, tfs-2015

In TFS it is possible to get build historical data on start screen. So when you log into TFS you immediately see the status of your builds. Can the same be achieved for displaying Code Coverage? This is something that SonarCube definitely does nicely.

Comment: Do you solve this issue with my solution?

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t the feature of include Code Coverage result in start screen. But you can [custom dashboard widget](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-dashboard-widget) with [test REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/testmanagement/restclient/testhttpclient2_2) to achieve that.

A simple sample to custom dashboard:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Custom widget</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="node_modules/vss-web-extension-sdk/lib/VSS.SDK.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        VSS.init({
            explicitNotifyLoaded: true,
            usePlatformStyles:true
        });
        VSS.require(["TFS/Dashboards/WidgetHelpers","TFS/TestManagement/RestClient"], function (WidgetHelpers,TFS_Test_WebApi) {
            WidgetHelpers.IncludeWidgetStyles();
            VSS.register("WidgetStarain", function () {

                var projectId = VSS.getWebContext().project.id;
                var getCodeCoverage = function (widgetSettings) {
                    return TFS_Test_WebApi.getClient().getBuildCodeCoverage(projectId, 252)
                           .then(function (buildCoverage) {
                               var $codeCoverageResult = $('div.codeCoverage');
                               var $codeCoverageObject = buildCoverage.coverageData[0].coverageStats;
                               var $detailResult = $codeCoverageObject[0].label + ": Total:" + $codeCoverageObject[0].total + ";covered:" + $codeCoverageObject[0].covered;
                               $codeCoverageResult.text($detailResult);
                               //$codeCoverageResult.text(JSON.stringify(buildCoverage))
                               return WidgetHelpers.WidgetStatusHelper.Success();
                           }, function (error) {
                               return WidgetHelpers.WidgetStatusHelper.Failure(error.message);
                           });
                }
                return {
                    load: function (widgetSettings) {
                        var $title = $('h2.title');
                        $title.text('starain widget custom');
                        return getCodeCoverage(widgetSettings);
                    }
                }
                //return {
                //    load: function (widgetSettings) {
                //        var $title = $('h2.title');
                //        $title.text('starain widget custom');
                //        return WidgetHelpers.WidgetStatusHelper.Success();
                //    }
                //}
            });
            VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="widget">
        <h2 class="title">widgets starain</h2>
        <div class="codeCoverage">non code coverage</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

After that, you can add that widget to the dashboard and check code coverage.